# How to join a table with multiple foreign keys from the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Stupid question, but I couldn't find the right search for this question and I'm having a mind block.  I have a table with keys from a reference table and I want to avoid using a loop to select the records without having duplicates.  I need to get Mode 1-5 joined so I can get the names without having duplicates.  Please leave comments so I can clarify.

Mode(1-5) are ModeIDs

Example:

Table to Join

```
ID
Mode1
Mode2
Mode3
Mode4
Mode5
```

Reference Table

```
ModeID
ModeName
```

Comment: Please consider including example input and output.

Comment: Why is your DB designed like this instead of with a Join Table?

Comment: Don't ask, supervisor forced me to do this.  We don't have time to revise it.  I had that design originally.

Comment: It would be fun using an unpivot, then pivot back the result :-) Sorry, no time for elaborating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the answer to your question:

```
SELECT 
    m1.ModeName,
    m2.ModeName,
    m3.ModeName,
    m4.ModeName,
    m5.ModeName
FROM Modes m
LEFT JOIN Ref m1 on m1.ModeID = m.Mode1
LEFT JOIN Ref m2 on m2.ModeID = m.Mode2
LEFT JOIN Ref m3 on m3.ModeID = m.Mode3
LEFT JOIN Ref m4 on m4.ModeID = m.Mode4
LEFT JOIN Ref m5 on m5.ModeID = m.Mode5
```

But I would suggest that there's a problem with your DB design. You should be using a join table.

Comment: Obviously fill in table names with whatever they actually are.

Comment: This is perfect.  Yes, I do know the Join table is correct.  That was my initial design, but my manager/supervisor doesn't approve of this... so I scrapped it and made what they wanted.  I tried.  Thanks again!

Comment: Hey at least you have this fun project to look forward to: "Add Mode5 through Mode10"

Comment: And then you'll get to start accounting for `NULL` values on nullable fields. Oh joy!

Comment: @xivo : maybe unpivotting the table in a view would help with the bad design for most future queries. Added an answer on the subject. Hope this wil help

Answer (score 1):

I think unpivoting the table in a view would help overcome the table design on the long run for many of your select queries. ( Especially when someone will have the genius idea to addd a sixth mode :-)

```
CREATE VIEW UnpivotedTable AS
    SELECT 
        ID, Mode, ModeId 
    FROM 
        TableToJoin
    UNPIVOT (ModeId FOR mode IN (Mode1,Mode2,Mode3,Mode4,Mode5)) AS t
GO
```

Your query would then become a rather "classic" PIVOT query (but that's not really the point of my answer. The unpivotting view is)

```
select Id, Mode1, Mode2, Mode3, Mode4, Mode5
from (
    select 
        Id, Mode, ModeName 
    from 
        UnpivotedTable 
            inner join 
        ReferenceTable 
            on ReferenceTable.ModeId = UnpivotedTable.ModeId
        ) as sourcetable
    pivot (
        max(ModeName) 
        for Mode in (Mode1, Mode2, Mode3, Mode4, Mode5)
        ) as pivotTable
```

Hope this will help on the long run. Sorry for the late answer

Comment: Yes, it would help me on future projects.  However, the modes won't ever increase and I'm sure of this unless the world agrees on this change, (they are "days" in case anyone else tries to add something to a finished question)  thanks though jbl!